# Efficient way to update one-to-many relationship table on an SQLite database

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update, sql-like

I have an SQLite database with two tables with a one-to-many relationship as follows:

```
People
`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
`unique_identifier` VARCHAR(200)

Address
`id` VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`people_id` INTEGER,
`includes_unique_indentifier` VARCHAR(256),
`name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(people_id) REFERENCES People(id)
```

There are some records within the `Address` table that have their `people_id` as `null`. For these addresses, which person they belong to, can be identified by regex matching `People.unique_identifier` to `Address.includes_unique_identifier`.

Ignoring the data redundancy, I want to update every `Address.name` to match its corresponding `People.name` record.

Currently my query looks like follows:

```
UPDATE address
SET name = (
  SELECT notes
  FROM people
  WHERE address.people_id = id OR address.includes_unique_indentifier LIKE ("%" || unique_identifier || "%")
)
```

From my understanding, this is an inefficient query because it will look through the Address table and recursively run the subquery for every record in the table. I am looking for a way to perform this update efficiently. The version of SQLite I am using does not support the `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` query.

Currently, no indices exist on the `Address` table.

Comment: There is no other way for your version of SQLite. You have to use a correlated subquery and the problem is that the operator LIKE most probably would not use an index even it existed. You could also try the operator GLOB: `address.includes_unique_indentifier GLOB ("*" || unique_identifier || "*")`

Comment: @forpas Thanks for the clarification. I think the `LIKE` and `GLOB` operator are identical except the latter uses Unix regex matching but in both cases the index wouldn't be used if I am correct. So what's the advantage of this query over the one I have? 

Also to expand on your comment, lets say I did upgrade to a higher version of SQLite, what would the query be to make it more efficient?

Comment: LIKE and GLOB are similar but not identical. I proposed GLOB as an alternative to be tested. For a query that uses the UPDATE...FROM syntax check my answer.

Comment: Marked you as the answer although the answer is the query I initially used only to find it wasn't supported by the version of SQLite I was using. So anyway, seems like there isn't a good solution unless I upgrade. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to upgrade to a version that supports the `UPDATE ... FROM ...` syntax (3.30.0+), you can use this query that simulates a join of the tables:

```
UPDATE address AS a
SET name = p.name
FROM people AS p
WHERE p.id = a.people_id OR a.includes_unique_indentifier LIKE '%' || p.unique_identifier || '%';
```